# read and store the C string value

Tags: c, string, struct

The instruction wanted me to read and store the C string value the user enters into the appropriate Name member.

***Code***

```
struct Name {
    char firstName[31];
    char middleInitial[7];
    char lastName[36];
};



struct Name coolname={{0}};

printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
scanf("%31s[^\n]", coolname.firstName);
```

***Two questions:***

- Did i read and store the c string value correctly?
- Are there any other ways of doing it and cons pros?

Comment: Change `%31` to `%30` to leave room for the NUL string terminator. Also the format spec has a wrong `s` it should be `%30[^\n]`

Comment: ok, ty, are there also another way of doing  scanf("%30[^\n]", coolname.firstName); ?

Comment: I would use `fgets` and [remove the trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Comment: ... but then you'd need to have a buffer that has space for that newline too...

Comment: `fgets(coolname.firstName,sizeof(coolname.firstName),stdin);`

Comment: in any case, you should check the return value

Comment: so if i change %31 to 30 and remove "s", then its correct?? if so, do i do it for every name?? like

 firstName[31] =   scanf("%30[^\n]", coolname.firstName);
char middleInitial[7];  = scanf("%6[^\n]", coolname.middleInitial);

Comment: @EsmaeelE Good start, yet problems with `fgets(coolname.firstName,sizeof(coolname.firstName),stdin);`  1) `'\n'` is in the name, 2) no check on return 3) trouble brews with names 30 characters or more.

Comment: Another choice is to use `fscanf(stdin, "%30s[^\n]", coolname.firstName);`

Comment: @EsmaeelE `"%30s[^\n]"` is a wrong alternative. It is not close to the needed functionality.  Review the errant need for the `s` in the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

`'s'` not needed: `scanf("%31s[^\n]", coolname.firstName);` attempts to read input without spaces up to 31 characters and then read a <kbd>[</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>any white spaces</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd>.

Certainly a no-`'s'` is one step better: `scanf("%31[^\n]"...` as that will attempt to read up to 31 non-`'\n'` chracters.

Yet this will not consume the trailing `'\n'`.

---

Recommend to read all user input with `fgets()`.  Perhaps as a helper function.

```
int read_line(const char *prompt, char *dest, size_t n) {
  fputs(prompt, stdout);
  fflush(stdout);

  dest[0] = '\0';
  char buf[n*2 + 2];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) return EOF;

  size_t len = strlen(buf);
  if (len > 0 && buf[len - 1] == '\n') { // lop off potential \n
    buf[--len] = '\0';  
  }

  if (len >= n) { //  maybe add a `len == 0` test
    return 0; // indicate invalid input, 
  }

  strcpy(dest, buf);
  return 1; 
}
```

Now use the helper function

```
if (read_line("Please enter the contact's first name: ", coolname.firstName, sizeof coolname.firstName) == 1) {
  // Oh happy day, got first name
}
if (read_line("Please enter the contact's middle name: ", coolname.middleInitial, sizeof coolname.middleInitial) != 1)) {
  // Oh happy day, got middle name
}
if (read_line("Please enter the contact's last name: ", coolname.lastName, sizeof coolname.lastName) != 1)) {
  // Oh happy day, got last name
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: Is `scanf("%31s[^\n]", coolname.firstName);` version consume `\n` in string that stored?

Comment: @EsmaeelE No. Think of `"%31s[^\n]"` as `"%31s"`followed by an attmept to scan 4 things `"["`, `"^"`, `"\n"`, `"]"`.   It is **not** what you want.  Who or what text suggested putting an `s` in `"%31s[^\n]"`?

Comment: simply i think we put s at first `scanf()` argument because of scanning a string. somthings like `scanf("%s", string)`

Comment: is there any soulotion with using `getline()` in this case, i cant implement a working example.

Comment: @EsmaeelE `scanf("%s", string)` will stop at the first whitespace and has no length constraint. So for my name it would only read "Weather".

Comment: @EsmaeelE I am unsure of who [we](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081766/read-and-store-the-c-string-value/55082145?noredirect=1#comment96910548_55082145) is.   Re: [is there any soulotion with using getline()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081766/read-and-store-the-c-string-value/55082145?noredirect=1#comment96910548_55082145),suggest posting that question.